# How to block a thread until a slot is received

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qthread, qmutex

I'm using Qt 6.6.1.

I defined a class MyThread:

```
class MyThread: public QThread
```

As an inner class, I defined a class WakeUpEvent in the private section of the .h file:

```
private:
    class WakeUpEvent : public QEvent {
    public:
        static const QEvent::Type EventType = static_cast<QEvent::Type>(QEvent::User + 1);

        WakeUpEvent() : QEvent(EventType) {}
    };
```

Then, I override the event method:

```
protected:

    bool event(QEvent* event) override {
        if (event->type() == WakeUpEvent::EventType) {
            // Wake-up event received
            condition.wakeOne();
            return true;
        }

        return QThread::event(event);
    }
```

In the private section, I defined 3 variables:

```
QMutex mutex;
QWaitCondition condition;
bool shouldContinue;
```

Finally, I defined a public slot:

```
void MyThread::TaskCompleted()
{
    shouldContinue = false;

    // Send wake-up event to the thread
    QCoreApplication::postEvent(this, new WakeUpEvent());
}
```

In my code, I block the thread execution this way:

```
shouldContinue = true;
emit signalForAnotherThread();
// Sleep until wake-up event is received
while (shouldContinue) {
   mutex.lock();
   condition.wait(&mutex);
   mutex.unlock();
}
```

`signalForAnotherThread` is a signal to which is connected another thread that I can call thread2. thread2 will perform some tasks, and at the end, it will emit the signal to which the slot `TaskCompleted` is connected.

I'm sure, as I tested through breakpoints, that the signal from thread2 for the slot `TaskCompleted` is emitted. But `TaskCompleted` is never reached (I checked through breakpoint).

The last line code executed in MyThread block is:

```
condition.wait(&mutex);
```

What is my mistake?

`TaskCompleted` is connected to the signal emitted by thread2 this way:

```
connect(thread2, SIGNAL(tasksCompleted()), this, SLOT(TaskCompleted()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Comment: Probably unrelated: don't use the SIGNAL/SLOT macros in new code. Especially not in Qt 6.

Comment: I do not think this approach can work. If you block the event loop slots will not be invoked.

Comment: I removed the SIGNAL/SLOT macros but this didn't fix the issue.

Comment: I tried to change approach by using QEventLoop instead of QMutex and QWaitCondition. I connect the signal emitted from the thread2 to the slot quit of a QEventLoop and I block the code with loop.exec() . It doesn't work and the behaviour is the same.

Comment: If nothing else, you have a data race on `shouldContinue`. One thread modifies it while another checks it, with no protection from concurrent access.

Comment: Instead of posting an event in `MyThread::TaskCompleted()`, just call `condition.wakeOne()` right there. Waking up blocked threads is kinda the whole point of `QWaitCondition`. Drop your `WakeUpEvent` machinery.

Comment: With event loops idling when there is no signal sent, what do you need to pause a thread for?

Comment: Get rid of the event loop. It's doing nothing, it's idling. If you have a signal/slot mechanism, that should be used to trigger code that's needed. As to thread-safety of your data, one way to achieve that is to move your data to its own QObject and allow any thread to access it via signal/slot.

Comment: Do not subclass QThread, if you plan to receive Qt events. QThread is _thread controller_,  and lives in a different thread than it controls. Mixing the code running in the thread, and the QThread object controlling it in the same class is a recipe for a messy, buggy, hard to understand code.

Answer (score 1):

I changed my approach, and now it is working.

In my MyThread class, I removed QMutex and QWaitCondition. I let only a bool value to decide if MyThread must continue its execution:

```
bool shouldContinue;
```

Then I execute this code:

```
//Do something -> thread logic
shouldContinue = false;
emit signalForAnotherThread();
WaitForCompletion(shouldContinue);
//Do something -> thread logic
```

`WaitForCompletion` is the following method:

```cpp
void MyThread::WaitForCompletion(const bool &bTermination)
{
   //Waiting another thread completes its task and emits signal
   while (!bTermination)
   {
      //Process Events for max 100 msec.
      QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 100);
      QThread::msleep(100);
   }
}
```

In the connect instruction, I abandoned the use of SIGNAL / SLOT macros as suggested.

```
connect(&thread2, &Thread2Class::taskCompleted, &myThread, &MyThread::TaskCompleted, Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Finally, in `TaskCompleted` slot, I set up `shouldContinue` to `true`:

```
void MyThread::TaskCompleted()
{    
  shouldContinue = true;
}
```

Comment: You must use atomics even for boolean flag: `std::atomic<bool> shouldContinue;` and same for the ref parameter of course.